# Issue with the debugging in php

Tags: php, debugging, wamp

I am running a`php`script which have a
while loop and file writings which make it take some time.The problem comes when it doesn 't seems to print the errors at the run time it prints them after complete execution of the script, and sometimes error is in loop so it repeat every time with loop  and it cost me a lot of time. I am using Wamp Server Version 2.2 .

here is sample `code`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Algorithm" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Delta Compression</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//DB Connection
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "delta_compression";
$dbhost = "localhost";

//Database Connection
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
echo "Database Connected !";

//Variable declaration 
$file="flag_track.txt";
$result=mysql_query("select * from d_5");
$total_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
$limit=256;

while($i < $total_rows){
    //increasing time limit 
    set_time_limit(0);
    //getting the value from the row of reading
    $reading=mysql_result($result,$i,'reading');
    //if first flag is set 
        if(!(firstFlag())) {
            delta();
            }
    //convert the decimal to binary and store in db 
    if(saveDelta(decbin($diffrence))== flase){
        echo"Error saving the data in DB";

        }   

}
function delta(){

        $delta=$flag-$reading;
        file_put_contents ($file, $flag."<br>".$delta, FILE_APPEND)."<br>";             
        if( $delta > $limit){
                $flag=$reading;
                file_put_contents ($file, $flag."<br/>".$delta,     FILE_APPEND)."<br>";

                }
}

function firstFlag(){
if($flag == null){
        //set the flag
        $flag=$reading;
        //saving the flag 
        file_put_contents ($file, $flag, FILE_APPEND)."<br>";
        return true;
        }
        else {

return false;
}
}


function saveDelta($dif) {

if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO e_x_1 (delta_of_reading) VALUES ('b" . $dif . "')")){
return true; //on success
} else {
return false; //on failure
}

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What IDE are you using because then it will be easier to set breakpoints and single step through the code

Comment: Dreamweaver is a WYSIWYG editor. I was meaning something like Zend IDE. If you are going to do a lot of PHP programming then it is worthwhile investing your time (Zend is not free) learning to use it. This will give you a starting point to pick one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_editors

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this statement

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO e_x_1 (delta_of_reading) VALUES (b'$dif')");
```

It should be something like:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO e_x_1 (delta_of_reading) VALUES ('b" . $dif . "')"); 
//i don't know if you want `b` there or it is an error
```

And since the function `saveDelta($dif)` is called inside while loop it will print the error multiple times. You can return error code and check for the successful execution of the query.

```
function saveDelta($dif) {

  if(   mysql_query("INSERT INTO e_x_1 (delta_of_reading) VALUES ('b" . $dif . "')") ){
    return true; //on success
  } else {
    return false; //on failure
  }

}
```

And in your while loop check as:

```
if( saveDelta(decbin($diffrence) === false ){
  //print error and return or do whatever you like to do
}
```

Comment: well that gives error on 
`if(   mysql_query("INSERT INTO e_x_1 (delta_of_reading) VALUES ('b" . $dif "')") )` and on `else`

Comment: Oh sorry i missed the `dot`. check the edit. I haven't checked it...just typed the code directly...

Comment: and by the way i wanted to know that how to make the errors print at run time. The text even i write in Html before `<?php?>` wont get print all it prints after complete execution. i think its doing recursively which makes my computer lag after running this code